# Single GIT Repositiory for Microservices and Deployments

Tags: git, kubernetes, microservices

I would like to ask you if you have experience in having a single GIT repository in which all the microservices/components are in it, togheter with all the deployment scripts, like k8s and Terraform.

How do you tag the code and branches?

How do you manage CI/CD pipelines?

I am looking for insights and experience from you guys!

Marco

Comment: As explained in 2nd edition of Kubernetes Up & Running, I think it is best to keep the app and the yaml in two different repositories. They belong to different parts of the pipeline and you don't want to trigger a new build when updating the config. https://www.amazon.com/Kubernetes-Running-Dive-Future-Infrastructure-ebook/dp/B07YP1XSZ9/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3GXJE7JROLJRQ&keywords=kubernetes+up+and+running%2C+2nd+edition&qid=1583176505&sprefix=kubernetes+up+and+%2Caps%2C223&sr=8-1

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/git-based-ci-cd-pipeline-for-monorepo